# Python Windows Service: access denied when calling SetTokenInformation

Tags: python, session, windows-services, access-denied

I have Windows service written on Python. What I need to do is to start some application from this service in the specified user session. The service is running in session 0, so I the algorithm I use is the next:

1. Get token from current service, which has (it should have, actually) full system rights.
2. Duplicate it.
3. Assign the session ID I want to the duplicated token.
4. Run application with the duplicated token using "CreateProcessAsUser" function.

I have the same stuff written on C++ windows service, and it works perfectly. As to Python, I catch "Access denied" when trying to call "SetTokenInformation" function. Probably, somebody has an idea, why this happens, or maybe can share another way to start the process in some user session by ID from the windows service?

Here's some code:

```
class AppServerSvc (win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
_svc_name_ = "TestService"
_svc_display_name_ = "Test Service"

def __init__(self,args):
    win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
    self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None,0,0,None)

def SvcStop(self):
    self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
    win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

def SvcDoRun(self):
    servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                          servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                          (self._svc_name_,''))
    self.main()

def get_next_msg(self):
    address = ('localhost', 6000)
    listener = Listener(address, authkey='secret password')
    conn = listener.accept()
    msg = conn.recv()
    listener.close()
    return msg

def process_msg(self):
    token = win32security.OpenProcessToken(win32process.GetCurrentProcess(), 
                 win32security.TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS)

    duplicated = win32security.DuplicateToken(token, 2)

    curr_proc_id = win32process.GetCurrentProcessId()
    curr_session_id = win32ts.ProcessIdToSessionId(curr_proc_id)

    # access denied! error code: 5
    win32security.SetTokenInformation(duplicated, win32security.TokenSessionId, curr_session_id)

def main(self):
    while True:
        msg = self.get_next_msg()
        self.process_msg()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
```

Answer (score 1):

On windows 10, running as administrator, with activepython 2.7 32 bit latest + pywin32 latest, your code works perfectly.

I recommend trying with ActivePython and updateing your pywin32 and then shutting down your anti-virus and retrying your code.

Comment: Thanks you very much for devoting your time for the question and trying out this example. Did you manage to run the code above and not to get any error after SetTokenInformation was called?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use DuplicateTokenEx instead of DuplicateToken:

```
    duplicated = win32security.DuplicateTokenEx(token, 
                                                impersonation_lvl, 
                                                win32security.TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, 
                                                win32security.TokenPrimary)
```

Then SetTokenInformation works well and doesn't fail with access denied error.

Answer (score 0):

For folks coming here from a search engine, I found what might be a workable solution. Have your service call this method to launch a given process as the current user:

```
import win32api
import win32process
import win32ts


def launch_as_user(self):
    try:
        console = win32ts.WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId()  # probably 1
        usr_token = win32ts.WTSQueryUserToken(console)
        command = 'C:/Windows/Notepad.exe'  # or whatever you want to run, naturally
        startupinfo = win32process.STARTUPINFO()
        startupinfo.lpDesktop = None  # use the current desktop for the session
        win32process.CreateProcessAsUser(
            usr_token,
            None,
            command,
            None,
            None,
            False,
            (win32process.NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS |
             win32process.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE),
            None,
            None,
            startupinfo,
        )
    except win32api.error:
        self.SvcStop()
```

If you run into issues starting a given executable (like I was, with a tkinter app built with pyinstaller), you can change command to:

```
command = f'explorer.exe {path_to_your_executable}'
```

This way, your app will be launched by Windows Explorer, effectively treating it like it was double-clicked on by the user as normal!